# PM2 stop in cluster mode

Tags: node.js, pm2, cluster-mode

By mistake , I run the following command on the server
`pm2start app.js -i 3500`

Now on server multiple instances are creating in cluster mode. Can anyone suggest how can i stop this ? And how can i delete already instances ?

Thanks

Comment: Answer can be found in PM2 docs.

Answer (score 2):

Pm2 generally gives a name to process group. You can check that with `pm2 list` and then run
`pm2 delete processname`

Or run `pm2 delete all`  to delete all processes

Comment: Is there a way where i can delete all cluster processes ? not fork types